# Maxent output clips to minimum extent of all input variables

Tags: interpolation, land-cover, ascii, maxent

I am experiencing an issue with the spatial extent of my output ASC files. I am using the UK Land Cover Map (LCM) 2007 at 25 metres resolution as a categorical variable in my Maxent modelling, alongside select continuous Bioclim variables interpolated (spline) to 25 metres and to the same extent. However, as the Bioclim files are originally at 1 km resolution, in some areas along the coastline they do not fully cover the sand dunes and mudflats covered the LCM which I am trying to model for.

The 'extent' of the Bioclim layer is the same as for LCM but these missing cells are given a 'No Data' value in the input ASCs. The output Maxent ASC extents are clipped to that of the Bioclim layers but I want them to extend to the extent of the LCM (which is included in the analysis and is in fact the 'most important' variable). Coastal sand dunes are an important habitat for my species and omission of these areas will negatively affect the accuracy of further connectivity analyses based on my Maxent outputs.

Is there a setting in Maxent to resolve this, or would I need to interpolate the input Bioclim layers outside of their original extent? If so, would this method have merit (bearing in mind that Bioclim is already an interpolated surface)?

[image: Maxent logistic output (red to green gradient) and underlying LCM 2007 (monochrome).]